# Gaming lag after GPU upgrade

Tags: graphics-card, gaming, lag

I recently bought a 4GB Gigabyte Nvida GTX 960 card, and the results aren't great when playing a computer game.

The game I've been testing as an example is FIFA 15. Previously I was running the spec below, however with 2x 1GB GTX 560 Ti (SLI) instead of the GTX 960. The game would run perfectly - it would maybe spike a minor lag every 10 minutes or so, but would run very smoothly the rest of the time.

Now, with the GTX 960, I'm getting lag every 2 seconds. Visually, everything is just slow and a bit jumpy. The audio quite literally lags at all times; as soon as a commentator speaks, it cuts off half way through and repeats from the beginning.

I have completely uninstalled the GTX 560 Ti drivers prior to installing the GTX 960's. I have also flashed my BIOS (after initially confirming there is game lag) per suggestion of Overclockers.co.uk, unfortunately to no avail.

As you'll see below, I don't have a particularly powerful CPU so I'm wondering if I just need to upgrade that? Should I need to, I'll swap out my RAM to all be the same HyperX type.

This is my overall system spec:
**Motherboard:** ASUS M5A99X EVO
**Motherboard Chipset:** AMD RD9x0
**Motherboard BIOS:** 1708
**CPU:** AMD Phenom II x4 955 @ 3.2GHz
**Memory:** 20GB (mixture of HyperX and another brand)
**PSU:** Corsair CS850M
**Graphics:** 4GB Gigabyte Nvidia GTX 960
**Graphics Driver:** 358.50

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Have you first of all tried changing your ram to two fastest sticks running in dual channel? Then try and see if that helps, if not then try a fresh install of Windows. Failing that I would advise to upgrade CPU and motherboard

Comment: reinstalling Windows did the trick - must have not uninstalled the previous drivers properly.